# Computing the pdf after clipping

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, information-theory

Given a random variable X with uniform distribution on [-b,b], I want to compute the probability density function of Y = g(X) with

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 0, ~~~x\in[-c,c]\\ x, ~~~\text{else} \end{cases}$$,

and $b>c$.

There is a discontinuity at $x = c$ and $x=-c$. Therefore, the distribution of Y has both an absolutely continuous component
$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{2b}$ on $y\in (-b,-c)$ and $y\in (c,b)$
and a discrete component.

This is the point, where I am not sure...my idea was the following:

The discrete component consists of two mass points at $-c$ and $c$. This results in
$$P_Y = \frac{b-c}{b} P_Y^{AC} + \frac{c}{b}P_Y^{D}$$

with

$AC$...absolutely continuous
$D$...discrete

Could this be right?

Comment: There is no density of $Y$ wrt Lebesgue measure; the answer you accepted is misleading in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density function of Y, as you already observed, is a mixed density with a discrete component. This component has probability $P(X \in[-c;c])=[c-(-c)]\cdot\frac{1}{2b}=\frac{c}{b}$

This because when $X \in [-c;c]$ Y concentrate all this mass of probability in one single value: $Y=0$

Thus this mixed density (not absolute continuous) is the following

$$  f_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{c}{b},  & \text{if $y=0$} \\
\frac{1}{2b},  & \text{if $y \in[-b;-c] \cup [c;b]$} \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: thank you! One more question: why is this discrete component located at $y=0$?

Comment: @Phinie :  because when $X\in[−c;c]$ Y concentrate all this mass of probability in one single value: $Y=0$. Look at the definition of your $g(x)$

Comment: thank you. if the clipper would be on an asymetrical interval, let's say $[-1,2]$, would the position of the discrete component change?

Comment: @Phinie : if the exercise is the same, the discrete componente will be always located in $Y=0$. What will change will be the probability value of this discrete component. Do a drawing of $g(x)$ to understand the procedure

Comment: ah thank you! It is because we set the value of Y in this interval to zero, right?

Comment: @Phinie: right!

Comment: okay now everything is clear, thank you a lot!